# Discord.JS - Cannot read property 'roles' of null

Tags: discord, discord.js

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null
at Object.process (/home/bots/fortnite-bot/commands/stats/stats.js:19:33)
```

Line (stats.js):

```
  let platform = message.member.roles.find(x => (x.id === psnRoleId) || (x.id === xboxRoleId))
```

Help please....

Answer (score 0):

Since Discord.JS v12 came out, instead of `message.member.roles.find()`, you must instead use `message.member.roles.cache.find()`. The function works in exactly the same way in the context you're using it, you just need to add the `.cache` in there.

Comment: I added this! Only the error did not disappear :(

`let platform = message.member.roles.cache.find(x => (x.id === psnRoleId) || (x.id === xboxRoleId))`

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null
    at Object.process (/home/bots/fortnite-bot/commands/stats/stats.js:20:33)`

Comment: That means that `message.member` is returning null. Is message definitely defined and set to a message?